# "Cannot find name" of global instance property when using Composition API with TypeScript in Vue 2.7

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-composition-api, volar

I'm working on upgrading an old **Vue** project that uses **TypeScript** and the **class component definition** style. Having upgraded Vue to version 2.7.13 I'm trying to migrate components to the **Composition API** style, but I have one specific problem - global instance properties don't seem to work anymore.

For example I have a global instance property called `$capitalize` added to `Vue.prototype` and using components in the old class-style the app works fine. I'm also able to get full type checking and Intellisense using module augmentation:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $capitalize: (string: string) => string,
  }
}

Vue.prototype.$capitalize = capitalize
```

however if I refactor the same components to use the Composition API VSCode shows me an error like so:

```
Cannot find name '$capitalize'. ts(2304)
```

and the component also doesn't render on account of that property missing.

I'm using **VSCode** with **Volar** and **Volar TypeScript Vue Plugin** and the built-in **TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features** extension disabled, as per the Volar docs.

I know that in Vue 3 you are meant to use [`app.config.globalProperties`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties) but this obviously isn't backported to Vue 2.7.

I tried using this shim in `types/sfc.d.ts`:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

I also tried messing with `tsconfig.json`, adding and removing these:

```
compilerOptions.jsx = "preserve"
compilerOptions.typeRoots
include
files
```

I tried using different flavors of the Composition API - with and without `defineComponent`, with and without `<script setup>`.

I saw in [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/60#issuecomment-521793766) that I can actually access the root instance in `onMounted`, so in that context `this.$capitalize` would work, but what if I want to use it outside of `onMounted`? What would be the "proper" way to provide something globally in the setup function of all components in Vue 2?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but perhaps worth mentioning that you could use vue-facing-decorator to continue using class components in Vue 3